# How to find out if the times are linked in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
time_values={'5874022': ['00:03:00', '00:08:00', '00:14:00', '07:43:00', '09:33:00', '17:18:00', '23:23:00'], '5873980': ['00:03:00', '03:49:00', '03:53:00', '13:33:00', '23:53:00'], '1548812': ['00:03:00', '12:18:00', '12:23:00'], '646944': ['00:08:00'], '1602678': ['00:08:00', '01:08:00', '01:48:00', '01:53:00', '01:58:00', '20:48:00'], '4124232': ['00:08:00', '00:14:00', '21:28:00', '21:33:00', '21:38:00', '21:43:00'], '5859013': ['00:14:00'], '1555064': ['00:18:00', '00:23:00', '06:08:00', '06:13:00', '07:58:00', '08:03:00', '09:18:00', '19:38:00', '20:08:00'], '645872': ['00:18:00', '00:23:00', '00:28:00', '07:28:00', '07:33:00', '08:38:00', '08:43:00', '08:48:00', '08:53:00', '09:23:00', '09:28:00', '09:33:00', '09:38:00', '09:43:00', '09:48:00', '11:13:00', '11:23:00', '11:28:00', '14:53:00', '14:58:00', '15:03:00', '15:08:00', '15:13:00', '15:18:00', '16:13:00', '16:18:00', '16:23:00', '16:33:00', '16:38:00', '17:08:00', '17:13:00', '17:18:00', '17:23:00', '17:28:00', '17:33:00', '18:23:00', '18:33:00', '18:53:00', '18:58:00'], '5605489': ['00:18:00', '00:23:00', '00:28:00'], '645873': ['00:23:00', '00:28:00', '00:34:00', '00:39:00'], '1575603': ['00:23:00', '00:28:00', '00:34:00', '00:39:00'], '1575605': ['00:23:00', '00:28:00', '00:34:00', '00:39:00', '17:33:00'], '1577854': ['00:23:00', '01:53:00', '21:13:00'], '1575604': ['00:23:00', '00:28:00', '00:34:00', '00:39:00'], '4120380': ['00:23:00', '04:23:00', '05:34:00', '05:38:00', '19:03:00', '19:38:00', '21:13:00'], '5659490': ['00:23:00', '00:28:00', '00:34:00', '00:39:00'], '5659489': ['00:23:00', '00:28:00', '00:34:00', '00:39:00'], '5659488': ['00:23:00', '00:28:00', '00:34:00', '00:39:00', '12:03:00', '21:18:00', '21:23:00', '21:28:00', '21:33:00'], '644457': ['00:23:00', '21:23:00', '21:28:00', '21:33:00', '21:38:00'], '647781': ['00:39:00'], '653461': ['00:39:00', '00:43:00', '03:49:00', '03:53:00', '03:58:00', '04:03:00', '04:08:00', '04:13:00', '15:13:00', '22:38:00', '22:43:00', '22:48:00'], '647782': ['00:39:00'], '2141244': ['00:39:00'], '1576737': ['00:43:00', '02:19:00', '02:23:00', '02:28:00', '02:33:00', '02:38:00', '02:43:00', '14:53:00', '14:58:00', '15:03:00', '16:13:00'], '1567035': ['00:43:00', '03:03:00', '03:08:00', '03:13:00', '03:18:00', '03:23:00'], '1548801': ['00:48:00'], '1556895': ['00:53:00'], '654052': ['00:53:00'], '4139733': ['00:53:00', '00:58:00', '01:03:00'], '642140': ['00:58:00', '03:13:00', '10:13:00', '21:13:00'], '6119951': ['01:03:00', '06:08:00', '06:13:00', '21:28:00', '21:33:00'], '4172822': ['01:03:00', '01:08:00', '01:13:00'], '384766': ['01:08:00', '01:13:00', '07:03:00', '08:58:00', '09:48:00', '14:23:00'], '377420': ['01:18:00', '01:23:00', '01:29:00', '01:33:00', '01:38:00', '01:43:00', '19:18:00'], '647637': ['01:18:00', '01:23:00', '01:29:00', '01:33:00', '19:08:00', '19:13:00'], '3591463': ['01:23:00', '01:29:00', '01:33:00', '01:38:00', '01:43:00', '01:48:00', '09:03:00', '10:08:00', '11:28:00', '11:33:00', '12:53:00', '13:28:00', '15:03:00', '15:28:00', '18:18:00', '18:53:00', '18:58:00', '19:53:00', '20:08:00'], '6201130': ['01:23:00', '01:29:00', '01:33:00']}
```

I need to find "linked times" (there is 5 or 6 minutes between them) in a segment.
For example `5874022` should be look like this:

```
time_values={'5874022': ['00:03:00', '00:08:00', '00:14:00'], ['07:43:00'], ['09:33:00'], ['17:18:00', ['23:23:00'], ...}
```

Edit:
Here is all my code:

```
shaped_timevalues = dict()
from datetime import datetime
fmt = '%H:%M:%S'
newlist= list()

for i,j in time_values.items():
    print('SEGMENTD:',i)

    for one in range(len(j)-1):
        one_hour = datetime.strptime(str(j[one]), fmt).strftime("%H")
        one_min = datetime.strptime(str(j[one]), fmt).strftime("%M")

        other_hour = datetime.strptime(str(j[one + 1]), fmt).strftime("%H")
        other_min = datetime.strptime(str(j[one + 1]), fmt).strftime("%M")
        if one_hour== other_hour and int(one_min) +10>= int(other_min):
            newlist.append(['%s:%s'%(one_hour,one_min),'%s:%s'%(other_hour,other_min)])
            shaped_timevalues.setdefault(i, []).append(['%s:%s'%(one_hour,one_min),'%s:%s'%(other_hour,other_min)])
        else:
            shaped_timevalues.setdefault(i, []).append(['%s:%s' % (one_hour, one_min)])
print(newlist)
print(shaped_timevalues)
```

It takes two values, and sometimes it repeats itself.
The output comes like this:

[image: screenshot]

Edit2:
As a result I want to create a new dictionary that in a segment if the values (times) are connected for example in **`5874022`**, the `'00:03:00'`, `'00:08:00'`, and `'00:14:00'` times are linked, so they have to be a list in that dictionary.

As a result, it should be like this:

```
time_values = {'5874022': ['00:03:00', '00:08:00', '00:14:00'],
                          ['07:43:00'], ['09:33:00'], ['17:18:00'], ['23:23:00'], ...}
```

Comment: Is the timing in your dictionary always in ascending order?

Comment: @VenkatJ every ID's or we can say key, yes it is in ascending order for values

Comment: What do you want to happen? What happens currently? Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and [ask], and [edit] your question to provide a description of what you want, what currently happens, and a [mre] that we can run and have it reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a sample of what output you expect/desire. Don't provide it as another almost unreadable screenshot, please.

Comment: @martineau I'm sorry sir, I really don't know how to edit more specific and clear statement. That's all I have :(

Comment: Twister: All I asked for what for you to add what the correct output would be given the time values you did provide. Not for all of them, just enough for someone to be able to judge whether their solution does what is needed or not.

Comment: @martineau I've edited my answer. I hope it helps now sir, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used your code as baseline, then built the following:

```
shaped_timevalues = dict()
from datetime import datetime
fmt = '%H:%M:%S'

for i,j in time_values.items():
    newlist = list()
    sequence = [j[0]] #list with the 'linked times', with the first value already inserted
    for n in range(1, len(j)):

        time1 = datetime.strptime(j[n-1], fmt)
        time2 = datetime.strptime(j[n], fmt)
        minutes = (time2 - time1).total_seconds()/60 #how many minutes in difference

        if minutes == 5 or minutes == 6:
            sequence.append(j[n])
        else:
            newlist.append(sequence)
            sequence = [j[n]]

    if len(sequence) > 0:
        newlist.append(sequence)
    shaped_timevalues[i] = newlist

print(shaped_timevalues)
```

This output looks like the one you asked:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AztPe.png)

Comment: Yes, thank you. That is exactly what I'm looking for.